# Add wrapping to JSON POJO without additional Wrapper classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to communicate with another application via REST that uses JSON with multi-layer wrapping.
e.g.:

I have the following POJO class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name="meta")
    private WrapperMeta metaParameters;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name="message")
    private WrapperMessage messageParameters;
}
```

the Wrapper class:

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name="parameters")
    private MetaParameters meta;
}
```

the JSON generated from it:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "parameters": {
        "service": "some",
        "sender": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Jane Doe"
        }
    }
  },
  "message": {
    "parameters": {
      "message": "hi"
      "sent": 1630597537
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get rid of the Wrapper classes, and instead have a more elegant solution.

e.g., with Annotations, like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="meta")
    @XmlElement(name="parameters")
    private MetaParameters metaParameters;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="message")
    @XmlElement(name="parameters")
    private MessageParameters message;
}
```

But the **XmlElementWrapper** annotation only seems to add the wrapping for XML, not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `@XmlElement` with `@JsonProperty`. Like this,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    @JsonProperty("meta")
    private WrapperMeta metaParameters;
    
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private WrapperMessage messageParameters;
}
```

Change your `WrapperMessage` class like this.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class WrapperMessage {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private MetaParameters meta;
}
```

*Note: You can add `Getter` and `@Setter` in class level. Like above examples*